# How to split lines in a file, and have the output names be based on those lines

Tags: file, split, centos

I am using CentOS. I have a file that contains information like:

```
100000,UniqueName1
100000,UniqueName2
100000,UniqueName4
100000,SoloName9
```

I want to split this out into files, one for each line, each named:

```
[secondvalue]_file.txt
```

For an example:

```
SoloName9_file.txt
```

Is it possible to split the file in this fashion using a command, or will I need to write a shell script? If the former, what's the command?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.  Use the sed command to turn this file into a valid shell script that you can then execute.

```
sed -e 's/^/echo /g' -e 's/,/ >/g' -e 's/$/_file.txt/g' <your.textfile >your.sh
chmod +x your.sh
./your.sh
```

Note that trailing whitespace in the file would take some additional work.

Writing it into a shell script file gives you a chance to review it, but you can also execute it as a single line.

```
sed -e 's/^/echo /g' -e 's/,/ >/g' -e 's/$/_file.txt/g' <your.textfile | sh
```